# WHat hi hat is it?

Tags: sound-design, replication

I'm looking for this hi hat sound. As you can hear it's a lower one. I'm really interested into this sound and i couldn't fin it. Supose that any of you knows what sound it is or what library contains it and for me is so important. Your can hear this sound here:

http://www.beatport.com/track/promiscuous-original-mix/5628999

http://www.beatport.com/track/killer-queen-wade-and-artslaves-remix/5335203

It has strenght but it sound smooth

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a 909 to me, pitched down, but could have been through any number of resamples/repacks/rejigs since it was new.

Answer (score 2):

I'm turning this into an answer, not really because it's necessarily the right answer, but because I discovered a very cool web page about 909 cymbals.

Drilling down the waffle on this thread - [analog 909 hi hats](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/electronic-music-instruments-electronic-music-production/438818-analog-909-hi-hats.html) on Gearslutz led me to a page where someone has actually built their own 909 circuitry, using [with permission, stunningly] the original 909 ROM samples & original schematics.

A round of applause to [Colin Fraser](http://www.colinfraser.com/tr909/my909.htm) for not only doing this, but providing the original samples to the rest of us, to muck up in whatever way we choose.